# Java NetworkInterface methods failing

Tags: java, networking

Having an issue with the product I code for where our licensing service is unable to find a host MAC address. We don't have much idea why this is happening and it is only happening to very small percentage of users.

The method to get this MAC address is using the Java NetworkInterface methods. If this fails and returns NULL (or users JRE is <1.6) we then fall back to using Sigar to get our address. However it seems this is also failing. The problem is either that it can't obtain the IP address (and then further to this can't get the MAC address) or just can't get the MAC. This issue is happening across all OS' we support (AIX, Solaris, Win7/8, Win Server, Linux & MAC).

As such, my first thought was that these users were enabling the Java security manager (as this is a common factor), but this is looking less likely as I try to reproduce it as this requires a lot of extra configuration steps with permissions to even get our product to run. As such we would have expected to see users asking us for what they need to enable to get our software to run, but this does not happen.

As such I am wondering what is causing this to fail. My only lead now is that it is something lower level (within the OS) that is being enabled to block Java's attempts to natively get this information. I am searching for this now, but it is slow going and an odd thing to search for.

My question is, is this kind of behavior possible (i.e. disabling calling of native methods to discover network info to anything other than trusted code within the OS?), on any/some of the platforms listed above?

Has anyone had this problem before with Java NetworkInterface methods?

Comment: Apologies if this is a little broad. I've been looking at this for some time, but am just wanting to see if the community can provide any insight to assist me in investigating further.

Comment: You are aware that the MAC address can be changed by the user? And therefore is completely useless as a unique system identifier for licensing purposes?

Comment: Yeah man I'm aware of it's sheer uselessness in identifying anything. However this is what the bosses want to use. I'm the lucky sod that has to figure the issue. Regardless of how fit for purpose it is ;)

Comment: Is it possible your clients are running the applications within a chroot?

Comment: what if your clients are running the program inside a virtual machine, and thus interfaces behave in a strange way? is it possible?